# Understanding how the compiler resolves pointer to functions

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

The following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

void does() { std::cout << "do" << std::endl; }
void does(bool b = false) { std::cout << "do(bool)" << std::endl; }

void fwd(void (*func)(bool))
{
    func(false);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    fwd(&does);
    fwd(does);
    fwd(*does);
}
```

understandably produces the following error:

`test.cpp:15:10: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information`

The compiler cannot discern which of the functions I intend to use.
What I don't understand is why the code will correctly run when I comment out the line that reads:

`fwd(*does)`

**Why can the compiler suddenly resolve the ambiguousness?**

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    fwd(&does);
    fwd(does);
}
```

Also, without overloading `does` the snippet will correctly run with all 3 calls.
This snippet runs fine...

```
#include <iostream>

void does(bool b = false) { std::cout << "do(bool)" << std::endl; }

void fwd(void (*func)(bool))
{
    func(false);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    fwd(&does);
    fwd(does);
    fwd(*does);
}
```

I'm compiling this with gcc 4.6.3 on a Linux box.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: that's funny, i don't see why `*does` makes any sense. it looks weird in the type tree point of view. but in the other two cases, it should be because of difference between prototypes and name mangling in the background.

Comment: I didn't think it made any sense either, I just tried it and it happened to compile. I was actually expecting it not to compile.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: It would be unexceptional, if `does` did not name an overload set instead of a single function, due to implicit conversion from function to function-pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator what prevents compiler from making the correct decision in the overload case? i am afraid `*` in front of a function name means something.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Simply, they never added a rule allowing it. See my answer for the actual rules.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can we then assume that the version that *does* work (without the overloaded set), simply works because the possibility for ambiguousness doesn't exist, and the compiler can correctly guess? Technically, it's "working under undefined behavior"?

Comment: No, the rules I quoted explicitly give the meaning of your first two calls, and equally explicitly disallow the last as "An overloaded function name shall not be used without arguments in contexts other than those listed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the overload-resolution rules for functions.
Specifically, there is an exception for using `&` before the function-name (once) not breaking overload-resolution, but none for using `*`.
Also see that only one of those two functions accept that single argument:

> #### 13.4 Address of overloaded function `[over.over]`
>
> 1 A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. **The function selected is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context.** *[ Note: That is, the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function type. —end note ]* The target can be
>
> - an object or reference being initialized (8.5, 8.5.3),
> - the left side of an assignment (5.17),
> - **a parameter of a function** (5.2.2),
> - a parameter of a user-defined operator (13.5),
> - the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion (6.6.3),
> - an explicit type conversion (5.2.3, 5.2.9, 5.4), or
> - a non-type template-parameter (14.3.2).
>
> **The overloaded function name can be preceded by the `&` operator.** An overloaded function name shall not be used without arguments in contexts other than those listed.

Quote is from n3242 (c++11), with bold by me.

Comment: You might want to mention section 5.3.1 (6): "The address of an overloaded function (Clause 13) can be taken **only in a context that uniquely determines which version of the overloaded function is referred to** (see 13.4)." Although I suppose it is arguable whether that applies to implicit decay-to-function-pointer. Anyway +1.

Answer (score 0):

`fwd` expects a function that takes a boolean parameter; you only have one such version of `does`, so there is no confusion.  In effect, `does` and `&does` are considered the same (because functions cannot be values, one of these two should technically be incorrect if not impossible to represent, but the language has to chosen to instead just treat them as the same thing).

But when you try to use `fwd(*does)`, you would need a definition of `does` that *dereferences* to such a function, and you don't have anything like that -- in fact, as I have been recently schooled, you *can't* have anything like that.

Comment: How is `&` and `*` different for your "explanation"?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, about needing a definition of `does` that dereferences to the expected prototype. But under that context shouldn't the version of the snippet without function overloads also fail?

Or, does it *not* fail, because without the possibility for ambiguousness the compiler can simply safely assume "he must mean this function", when I ask it to dereference `does`?

Comment: i am afraid `*` doesn't mean dereferencing when go to the level of function. you can't really dereference a function. dereferencing a function means the function itself. i went write two test program with `*` in front in c and c++, both show the address of the function itself in asm code.